# Html/Bootstrap DatePicker Date Time Format Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<input class="form-control  inputField inputFieldBoot" id='txtHolidayDate' type="text" datepicker="" data-trigger="#spnHolidayDate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<span id="spnHolidayDate" class="input-group-addon inputgroupaddonsign btnCalender"></span>
```

I am using this code for datepicker i need to change the format of date like this

`data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy"` i.e 01-DEC-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

The control you are using cannot display dates using short month names, it can only read them from the chosen date. Here is a link that shows the full set of properties and methods: http://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/

You can always use the original JQuery UI date picker, which works as shown in my original answer below.

**Original:**

There is not a lot of information in your question. But if you want to have the date format like 01-Dec-2015, the format you need to use is `dd-M-yyyy`, not `dd-MM-yyyy`.

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgjertsen/wuzva5fx/).

Here is the JQuery UI References:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: Sorry but in bootstrap data-date-format its is not working it is showing blank like this 10--2015

Comment: Sorry for not providing more information actually m simply using datetimepicker as i have mentioned above in my question but i need to get the format like 10-Dec-2015 but its coming by default 10/12/2015 and with data-date-format='dd-mm-yyyy' it is coming like 10-12-2015 and the way you asked me to use date format it is showing 10--2015 month is not coming

Comment: Sorry Karl but have tried this but it is not taking it is giving 10--2015

Comment: Do you have a URL I can look at?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Datepicker-Plugin-Datepicker/ m using this one only very first one

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle to my answer, showing it working. I set the date format in the binding, not in the date picker itself.

Comment: Hi Karl m using that two js file datepicker.min.js and prettify but you are using something else but i have tried your solution also but getting same result may be because of that two js file i have used...thnx anyway

Comment: Which JS files are you using? These are not mentioned in your question.

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Datepicker-Plugin-Datepicker/ this is the link where i get that two js files i have mentioned that earlier also datepicker.min.js and prettify.js...

Comment: This is a link to the demo, but there are no JS files mentioned.
Are you using JQuery? Are you using JQueryUI? Which other JS files are you adding to you page? Can you post them here?

Comment: I am using jquery                        jquery.min.js,bootstrap.min.js,bootbox.min.js,prettify.js,datepicker.min.js. Bootbox.js m using for some different purpose

Comment: Can you paste the **FULL LINKS** from your code? I'm trying to help, but I need all of the information.

Comment: I have those files in my local machine it not the link

Comment: Can you paste links to them in a CDN?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Datepicker-Plugin-Datepicker/prettify.js            http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Datepicker-Plugin-Datepicker/dist/datepicker.min.js

Comment: Really thankful to you m also trying ....may be i am somwhere wrong..m not getting it as i hv given the code above data-trigger and datepicker if i omit those and bind it dynamically the picker is working on textbox select but not on the datepicker icon click even m calling a function from that span

Comment: See my updated answer. the control you are using cannot do this. Sorry! I would suggest you look at a standard jQueryUI control.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: Thats fine Karl i will try to take the jqueryUI and customize it as per my requirement